# XPages computed custom control with custom properties

Tags: xpages

I found this blog post which defines how to compute your custom control, which is a great solution, but how do I pass custom properties for this custom control using the include tag:

http://www.jmackey.net/groupwareinc/johnblog/johnblog.nsf/d6plinks/XPages-How-to-Compute-a-Custom-Control-at-Runtime

Comment: Can't you just use a datacontext for this instead?

Comment: I am going to give that a go - thank you.

Comment: Just be a little careful when using `dataContext` as it stores objects in a scope variable which can lead to `java.io.NotSerializableException`. [This article](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/dx/Dos_and_Do_Nots_for_XPages_Scoped_Variables) describes dos & donts for scoped variables. You could also look into my [question of XPages development forum](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/xpagesforum.nsf/topicThread.xsp?action=openDocument&documentId=9109670A1CCB05268525797D0051CADF) which deals with `dataContext`.

Comment: Thanks Naveen for your tips.

Comment: Thank you Jeroen. Include didn't work for me, since you have to compute this at page load, so I ended up using rendered property since loaded is also on page load and my pager does a partial refresh. If you want to post your comment as an answer, I will be happy to accept this answer.

Answer (score 0):

There's now a dynamic view custom control in the ext. library. That might be a good solution for you.

Comment: Thanks David, will look into this, although I am trying to avoid views since they perform FTSearch by default, so I am using db.search to build my query.